# How to validate multiple inputs in a form

Tags: javascript, html

Please take a look at this code, I want to know how to validate all these input elements in this single form using JavaScript.

I know they look the same but i have the names in a separate div. Your corrections and contributions to my form will be very much appreciated.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Check this link for a simple validation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: you can check this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: what do you mean by " I know they look the same but i have the names in a separate div"

Comment: Each field needs its own name. The labels for your forms should be next or around them, and the form element should surround all the form content.

Comment: sorry i actually was supposed to say the that the labels are arranged elsewhere so that they dont magnet to the side of the fields.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can. Try this to Validate data in Java Script

```
 <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateData()">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="fname"><br><br> 
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>                   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Then You have to create a javaScript Function to Validate the data as above validateDate(), for this, now your code is

```
  <script>
    function validateData() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    //if name is empty
    if(fname == "" || username == "" || email == "" || password == "") {
    //SOme Error Code here
    alert("Please Fill All the Form Data.");
      }
     if(username.length < 4 || username.length > 20) {
    //SOme Error Code here
    alert("username must be less than 20 but more than 4 Characters.");
      }

     // You can add more filters like  password length, and so on by using more if conditions
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateData()">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="fname"><br><br>   
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>                    
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
```

That's all. :)

Comment: with a slight correction (change the first input ID to "fname") it works...but i still cant get it to work for "MULTIPLE INPUTS" in one form. To validate name, username, email, password etc in One form with javascript

Comment: You can validate as much as inputs with javascript. I have changed my code. You can also validate single input by adding more if conditions. Check it out

Comment: Yes! Yes this worked like a charm, although after prompting an alert it clears everything out but still i love it! Thank you very much. Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score -2):

Even though this requires jQuery, it can solve your problem:

To use jQuery Validate you just need to include in your code a version of the jQuery library equal or more recent than 1.7 and a file with the plugin.

See an example:

```
jQuery('form').validate();
```

After calling the jQuery.fn.validate method, you can validate your fields using data attributes, that are valid to the HTML5, according to the W3C.

See a example to required field:

```
<form>
<input type="text" data-required />
</form>
```

https://plugins.jquery.com/validate/

Comment: its for an assignment...and we must use javascript :(

Comment: @uoriwoh — jQuery is a JavaScript library, not a different programming language.